# Java 8 LocalDateTime has different results

Tags: date, datetime, java-8

I am trying to update some code to use Java 8's feature for parsing multiple date formats.  my local time on my box is set to **UTC-11**.

the below code works when using the SimpleDateformat.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date correctDate = dateFormat.parse("2018-09-6T03:28:59.039-04:00");

//Gives me correct date  
System.println( correctDate);//Wed Sep 5th 20:28:59 GMT-11:00 2018
```

I am trying to update this code to give the same date as above with the DateTimeFormatter in Java 8 , so i can handle another date format..

```
DateTimeFormattter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]XXX");
LocalDateTime updateDate = LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-09-6T03:28:59.039-04:00", dtf);

//shows the wrong date of 2018-09-06 03:28:59.039.
System.out.println( updateDate.toString() );// 2018-09-06 03:28:59.039
```

*[solved]*
I was able to fix this by using ZonedDateTime.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-09-6T03:28:59.039-04:00");
zonedDateTime = zdt.withZoneSameInstance(ZoneId.of("GMT"));

Date correctDate = Date.from( zonedDateTime.toInstance());
```

//correctDate is what i wanted  Wed Sep 5th 20:28:59 GMT-11:00 2018

Comment: Wrong class, `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment, as its class documention explains.

Comment: With Java 8 you don’t need to construct your formatter yourself. It’s built in as [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME). Also `OffsetDateTime` is a better class to use than `ZonedDateTime` here since what you’ve got and what you want is an offset like `+04:00` or GMT, not a zone like Australia/Brisbane or America/New_York.

Comment: Downvote with no reason?!! smh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you parse your date string into a `LocalDateTime` the zone offset is lost because `LocalDateTime` does not hold any time zone or offset information.
When you format the `LocalDateTime` to a string again, you'll only have the time as it was parsed without offset.

The [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) of `LocalDateTime` clearly explains this:

> This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays, combined with the local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

You should consider using `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: hi, yes...i was able to solve this by using ZonedDateTime. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, using OffsetDateTime as suggested in the accepted 'Answer':

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-09-6T03:28:59.039-04:00");
  Date correctDate = Date.from( odt.toInstant());